# Minimal setup to run elixir release in a fresh machine

Tags: elixir, release

### Background

I have a very minimal  Elixir desktop app called `hello-desktop`:
https://github.com/Fl4m3Ph03n1x/hello-desktop

Which I have compiled and released in a Windows 10 VM using `mix release`.

Now in another Windows 10 machine, I downloaded the repo and I have installed erlang for Windows:

- https://www.erlang.org/downloads

My thought process is that since I created the release with everything installed I should not need to install anything at all in the new machine to run my `hello.bat`.

```
releases: [
        hello: [
          include_executables_for: [:windows],
          applications: [runtime_tools: :permanent]
        ]
      ]
```

However, I still went ahead and installed erlang with OTP 24 to discard it as a possible mistake.

### Problem

The problem here is that when I run the bat file created by `mix release` in my second VM I get the following error:

```
 .\hello.bat start
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Which is very confusing. What path is it looking for?
In theory the VM should be all I need. I shouldn't need Elixir installed. To be honest, since I believe I am creating the release with everything included, I should not even need erlang installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this smells like a bug in relative paths of release files, I would recommend to look for issues in elixir repo or create one there, the windows platform may have more bugs since it is not that well maintained.

Comment: Is erlang in the PATH? Windows might be acting a bit weird with the user shell PATH and the batch file PATH. This error is annoying because it doesn't tell you the missing PATH. Check your environment variables, or modify the `.bat` to ECHO out the current PATH

Comment: But the confusing part is, why do I need erlang in the first place? 
The release should have everything by default, even the erlang runtime version right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

My mistake was to think that the single file called `hello.bat` was all I needed to run everything. In reality, as far as I now understand, that is only an entry point.

Turns out you *can* run an elixir release in a fresh machine, with everything included, if you bring along the full `_build` folder with you.

Basically, after zipping the entirety of the `_build` folder, sending it to a new fresh machine without Elixir or Erlang installed, and then unzipping it and running the `hello.bat` inside, everything worked.

I was also quite surprised. I don't know which files inside the `_build` folder are needed specifically, but I am guessing that everything inside of `_build/prod` is there for a reason and so should be brought with your release.

This is specially incredible to me, as it also include third part tools, like `:wx` should you need them.